# JQuery: Add cursor focus on input field on hover

Tags: jquery, input, focus

**Right now on hover the menu hides and the search box expands to fill the menu. How can I add focus to the search box and insert the flashing caret on this hover event and remove it on hover exit?**

```
<body>
    <input type="text" value="" id="search" class="noquery" />
</body>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#search").hover(function(){
            $("#navi1 ul").hide();
            $("#search").css("width","100%");
            },function(){
            $("#navi1 ul").show();
            $("#search").css("width","96px");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").hover(function () {
        $("#navi1 ul").hide();
        $("#search").css("width", "100%");
        $(this).focus(); // to focus
    }, function () {
        $("#navi1 ul").show();
        $("#search").css("width", "96px");
        $(this).blur().val('');  //to remove focus (blur)
    });
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v58Bz/1/)**

Comment: I'm sorry, I also meant that when the input field loses its focus on hover exit any text input is also cleared.

Comment: Works perfectly, you are a major stud @Sergio.

Comment: @oceanic815, great! Glad I could help! Please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.